Why the loop bandwidth must be much smaller than the input frequency to ensure settling behavior?
Razavi said, in Section 9.6 Loop bandwidth of his book RF Microelectronics that

In the design of PLLs, we impose... a loop bandwidth much smaller than the input frequency to ensure a well-behaved settling


and he gives a equation for this statement in the next page.
Eq.9.59

I understand that the left side of this equation (2.5 \$\omega_n\$) is derived from Eq 9.56 and Eq 9.57 (Eq 9.56 \$\Leftrightarrow\$ Eq 9.57)
Eq 9.57

that the bandwidth is obtained by equating the squared of magnitude loop transfer equation Eq.9.19 to 1/2.
Given that for Type II PLL,  \$\omega_n \$ and  \$\zeta \$ is equal to

I can't' see how there is any relation between  \$\omega_n \$ and the input frequency  \$ \omega_{in}  \$ of PLL that Equation 9.59 is suggesting?
What am I missing in here?
Here is the entire page of the reference I previously mentioned, page 645 and page 646



Do you understand how PLLs work? Do you understand what the input frequency and filter BWs relate to?
